# Are MATLAB related questions allowed in dsp.se?

Tags: discussion

For example, is the following a valid question?

> Which function can I use to implement the following filter
>   in MATLAB?
>
> [image]
>
> Can I use MATLAB [butter(_)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) function?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it's fine... except that you should probably explain a bit more about why you think `butter()` will do that job.

Comment: What about asking questions about Image Processing programs written in MATLAB?

Comment: Well, it depends on whether the question is about the algorithm implemented or about MATLAB. In general, [MATLAB questions are better to be answered on StackOverflow itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).   There's a grey area there, though, so feel free to ask on SE.SP --- but if it's closed I'm happy to migrate it to SO if that's what people think.

Comment: My answer to your original question is the same:  if the question is about the algorithm used by `butter` then that's fine here.  If the question is about how to use the parameters of `butter` then that's more of a SO question an an SP question.